# Get all files in a Directory and Get the newest one

Tags: c#, list, file, directory, operating-system

I'm trying to get all the files in a directory and to get the name of the newest one.

```
List<string> NewFiles = new List<string>();
NewFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path,, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
String lastItem = NewFiles.Last();
```

The problem is that i have 354 files in this folder and the last file i get from this is the  file 99.

Comment: It's a folder with inside only files, so i wanna get the newst one.

Comment: When using [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) instead, you get also the last modified date for each file.

Comment: I would take a look at `DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()` and order the results by `CreationTime`

Comment: The problem is that i get only 99 files and not 354.

Comment: do you want the file that was modified most recently or the file that was created most recently?  The answers below get the file that was modified most recently.  You would need to use the `FileInfo.CreationTime` property to get the file that was created most recently.

Comment: "I get only 99 files and not 354" - that was not clear from your question and - frankly - I doubt this is true.

Answer (score 4):

`Last()` will get you the file name which happens to be enumerated as last file. There is no specific ordering, so this might not be the file last written.

When using [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) instead, you get the information about the last modified time for each file.

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var allFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
var lastModifiedFile = allFiles.OrderBy(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

As Klaus said, you can use `LastWriteTime` property of `FileInfo` class to get the last file from that directory which is updated.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"<Your directory path>");
//This will get all files in the top directory
var newestFile = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) 
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)  //Sort(desc) by LastWriteTime
             .First();  //Take the first file
```

Answer (score 0):

If Just modify above query for specific pattern or specific file

```
string pattern = "*.txt";
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
var file = (from f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern) orderby f.LastWriteTime descending select f).First();
```

Or if you want to run recursively

```
public static FileInfo GetNewestFile(DirectoryInfo directory) {
   return directory.GetFiles()
       .Union(directory.GetDirectories().Select(d => GetNewestFile(d)))
       .OrderByDescending(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime))
       .FirstOrDefault();                        
}
```

and
call like this

```
FileInfo newestFile = GetNewestFile(new DirectoryInfo(@"your path"));
```